# Angular-UI ng-grid - issue with using 2 data grids on one page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am using ng-grid-2.0.11 to create data grids. I am creating 2 data grids on a page. The second one is not showing data.

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed when I specified width here:

```
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    height: 350px;
    width: 1075px;
}
```

Previous I had written it like

```
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    height: 350px;
}
```